# Invalid character stream macros

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor, string-concatenation, stringification

The following preprocessor macro:

```
#define _VARIANT_BOOL /##/
```

is not actually valid **C**; roughly speaking, the reason is that the preprocessor is defined as working on a stream of tokens, whereas the above assumes that it works on a stream of characters.

On the other hand, unfortunately the above actually occurs in a Microsoft header file, so I have to handle it anyway. (I'm working on a preprocessor implementation.)

What other cases have people encountered in the wild, be it in legacy code however old as long as that code may be still in use, of preprocessor macros that are not actually valid, but work anyway because they were written under compilers that use a character oriented preprocessor implementation?

(Rationale: I'm trying to get some idea in advance how many special cases I'm going to have to hack, if I write a proper clean standard-conforming token oriented implementation.)

Comment: Why do you have to handle it? Just because Microsoft have a non-standard preprocessor and non-standard headers that take advantage of it, it doesn't mean you need to handle it.

Comment: Well, the intent is to create tools that can do useful things with existing code. Tools that can't read Microsoft header files, even if they have the moral high ground by reference to the standard, would be less useful.

Comment: In that case I don't think your question has a definitive answer. What you need to support is entirely dependent on your target market. If you're writing a standards compliant preprocessor, that's one thing otherwise the extensions that you have to support depend on what environments you intend your product to be used in and that's entirely up to you (or entirely open ended).

Comment: I'm aiming for as close as I can reasonably get to 'any C code that's still in use in any environment'.

Comment: "any C code that's still in use in any environment". Surely you have to be joking? That's a simply vast amount of code and you're never going to get access to 99.99% of that and of the remaining fraction only a tiny number of projects will ever consider using a new tool with a new preprocessor.

Comment: I said _any_ not _all_. Of course any given new tool will only be run on a tiny fraction of C code, but there is no way to know in advance which fraction, and no reason to a priori rule out chunks like 'nothing that includes the Microsoft headers'.

Comment: So the problem is that when pasted together, `//` is not a valid *`pp-token`*?

Comment: Right. Not a valid pp-token, but needs to work anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant part of the standard *`(§6.10.3.3 The ## operator)`* says:

> If the result is not a valid preprocessing token, the behavior is undefined.

This means that your preprocessor can do anything it likes and still be standard conforming, including emulating the common behaviour.

I think you can still have a "token-based" implementation and support this behaviour, by specifying that when the result of the `##` operator is not a valid preprocessing token, the result is the two operand tokens unchanged.  You may also want to have your preprocessor emit a warning about the invalid code.